# Debug Eclipse from the moment plugin starts running

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to debug an Eclipse plugin, but I can't figure out where to place the breakpoints.

Is there anyway to set Eclipse to Debug every single expression so that from the moment I execute the plugin, the first expression is a breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Activator class, you can start with that.  Otherwise it's really a matter of what extensions you're contributing and when *those* will be called by someone else.  Plug-ins aren't like applications.  Set your breakpoints in your code, they'll trigger when code from your plug-in is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

A plugin is more than code and the code it might have doesn't need to be Java, but if it's Java code you want to debug, try setting [class load breakpoints](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/jdt_tips.html?resultof=%22class%20load%20breakpoints%22%20) on all of your plugin's classes.

Comment: This link doesn't mention anything about "Class Load Breakpoints"

Comment: Oops. Fixed link. You'll have to scroll down or Ctrl+F to get to the topic.